# -moz-transform breaks the select control by losing the display

Tags: css

Need quick help if any body have clue.

When I apply `-moz-transform:scale(1.45)` (any scalar), the dropdown list position changes from the dropdown Box.

[image]

```
{
    -moz-transform:scale(1.15);
    -moz-transform-origin: left top;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.15);
    -webkit-transform-origin:left top;
    zoom:115%;
}
```

Comment: because its resized from its original positon, you would have to equalize the position when you resize it

Answer (score 0):

When you apply a transform, it's a bit like a `position:relative` in that the element affects elements around it as if it were still in its original position. In this case, it seems like Firefox is using the `select`'s original position to show the options.

I don't think there's much you can do about that, but you could work around just by using `font-size: 125%` instead of transforming.

Comment: the issue was not resolved via this stratgey. the zoom functionality was done by doing font size and growing the whole design. Actually the desire was to creat the zooming functionality that did not worked for firefox. not only the position of drop down breaks. but also the navigation of drop down become hectic. so the solution was not successful via zoom. -moz-transform